# container-fluid keeps going to background even whenz-index is set

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I try to implamant a very simple wey of design. I want that the first part of the page will be with fixed position and when I scroll, the rest of the page will overlay it just like on sites like popcoren time here is an [exmple of site that uses that design](http://popcorn-time.to/) . Well I started building something but It wont work because the container-fluid bg allways goes to back and wont overlay the fixed content.
what I managed to do but its ugly - I changed the bg color of each of the child divs (of the container-fluid) and it seems to be working but as I said I am sure this is not the correct answer.

here is my  code:

```
<div id="bg_1"  style="background-image:url(img/bg_1.png); background-repeat:repeat;  background-attachment: fixed;background-size: 100% 100%; width:100%;  z-index:-1; ">
    <div style=" width:100%; font-family:Alef,sans-serif; color:#FFF;position:fixed;  ">
            <div class="jumbotron" style= "background-color:transparent; text-align: center;  color:#FFF;">
              <center>  <h1>blah blah</h1> </center>
              <center><h2>blah blah blah blah</h2></center>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <div class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:#CE1E1A;"><!--icon and animation area --> 
        <div class="row" >
             <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;  ">
                    <img src="img/icons/re_discover.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/meet_new_pl.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/peek_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        </br>
        <hr />   
    </div> <!--end of container fluid --> 

    <div class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:#CE1E1A;"><!--icon and animation area --> 
        <div class="row" >
             <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;  ">
                    <img src="img/icons/re_discover.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/meet_new_pl.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/peek_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        </br>
        <hr />   
    </div> <!--end of container fluid -->
    <div class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:#CE1E1A;"><!--icon and animation area --> 
        <div class="row" >
             <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;  ">
                    <img src="img/icons/re_discover.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/meet_new_pl.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-xs-12 " style="float:right; color:#FFF; text-align:center; background-color:#CE1E1A;">
                    <img src="img/icons/peek_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style=" margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px;">
                    <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Alef,sans-serif;" dir="rtl">blah blah</h1>
                    <span style="color:#FFD2D3; font-size:16px; font-family:Alef,sans-serif;">please help me please help me please help me please help me please help me</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        </br>
        <hr />   
    </div> <!--end of container fluid -->
```

here is an example:[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/VLXT5o0apv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change:

```
<div class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:#CE1E1A;">
```

to:

```
<div class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:#CE1E1A;position:relative;">
```

Comment: Great it worked... Can you please explain to me why?

Comment: if you set `div` into relative it means you are setting it into its normal position.